# GoGtk3 custom signals

Tags: go, go-gtk

I need to know how to write a custom signal in GoGtk3. Having a gui thread wherein gtk is working in, I want to update a textview from adjacent goroutine.

```
label,_:= gtk.LabelNew()

go func(){
   // This is listening to a websocket
   //update label
   for {
       c.ReadJSON(&frame) // c is my gorilla websocket 
       fmt.Printf("I received something %v\n", frame)
       // label.SetText("update ...") is not working properly

       }
}()
```

When using label.SetText method, I noticed that this is not working correctly. I suspect this is not thread safe and I should emit a signal instead. I appreciate if you lead me how.